# Which enemies take extra damage from sword attacks?

Tags: xcom-2

I have noticed that Ranger sword attacks do different amounts of damage to different enemies. For example, attacking with the basic sword against ADVENT troopers deals 3-5 damage, but attacking Sectoids deals 6-8 damage. Which other enemies are more vulnerable to sword attacks?

Comment: I'm not sure if the damage range on sectoids is 100% correct, but I do know they take extra damage. Also, I am explicitly not asking about the effects of armor. The sword has a higher base damage against certain enemies.

Comment: Yeah, I've only noticed the sectoid explicitly, but I usually stop using swords around mid-game, which means I don't usually see how much damage they do to the later enemies.

Comment: I use swords extensively all game, and haven't noticed extra damage to other enemies, for what that's worth. Bladestorm is a lifesaver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just Sectoids against which swords have +3, sadly.